# Изменить папку по умолчанию для расположения проектов PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Где в настройках можно задать месторасположение этой папки по умолчанию?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я сделал симлинк,.. но (вроде бы) некоторые функции могут работать некорректно (в частности, по-моему, `Xdebug` выпедривается) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таких настроек не существует - по умолчанию PhpStorm всегда использует `~/PhpstormProjects` (`~` - значение Java system property `user.home`). Однако, как только Вы выбрали другую директорию для создания проекта, он в слкдующий оаз будет предлагать выбранную директорию вместо директории по умолчанию. Поэтому значение по умолчанию, в общем-то, используется ровно один раз.

Если Вы хотите, чтобы эта настройка была добавлена в IDE, проголосуйте за [IDEA-151727](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151727)

Answer (score 2):

Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Project Opening -> Default directory